# Safety issues around using a new battery with an old laptop

Tags: laptop, battery, netbook

I recently bought a new battery for my netbook. The netbook was made in 2010.

I'm guessing the replacement battery was probably manufactured around the same time. (I just can't picture any companies making new batteries for something like this a year or two past the date the system was released, but I could be wrong)

The battery was at 0% when I got it.

I don't know if I'm allowed to post the company I bought the battery from, or the brand of battery, so I won't for now.

I charged it up and let the battery drain to 60% over the course of several hours. It seems decent enough, I don't need crazy battery life, just something longer than 10 minutes, which is what my old OEM battery sadly was down to.

So with this new battery...how carefully do I need to keep an eye on it? What is the risk of bulging or fire? I'm less concerned about how well the battery might work, and more concerned with safety risk.

This is the first time I have bought a replacement battery for any hardware, and I simply don't know what the risks are.

Comment: Do you have a specific concern or question, or are you just looking for general advice or recommendations? We can answer a specific question, but I'm not sure you have one here yet.

Comment: Do I need to keep an eye on it while it's charging? If so, for how many days until I can consider it "safe"? Can I leave it charging overnight? What are (roughly) the odds of it bulging? Closer to 1 in 3, or closer to something like 1 in 50,000? What are (roughly) the odds of it catching fire? Closer to 1 in 3, or closer to something like 1 in 50,000? Was it likely manufactured around 2010 or more recently than that? Does that matter for safety issues? If it bulges a tiny bit, is it still safe to use?

Comment: Where did you buy the battery? It’s fine to mention such things as long as it’s not some kind of spam. Anyway, some third party battery brands are obviously going to be better than others. As for the manufacturing date, again it comes down to brand. A few companies like Cameron Sino seem to continue making compatible batteries long after the originals are unavailable. There may be a date code somewhere on the battery if you look carefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will get an answer to these questions as there is no
statistical data for it.

If you're worried, just keep an eye for strange computer behavior and
for high unexplained temperatures inside the case. Don't leave it charging
over-night until you have more confidence in it.

Battery failure is usually a gradual happening, rather than sudden,
so the warning signs come much before the hard failure, unless the
battery is badly built to start with (probably not your case).

One useful utility to keep an eye on the temperature sensors is
[Core Temp](https://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/)
and
[its alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/core-temp/),
or search for such a product via Google.
I can't recommend any one product, as it's been a long time since
I used any, but some will display the temperatures in the
notification bar and will have alerts you can program.